# How to use the .on() in jquery with multiple event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my current function:

```
$('.EmailAddresses').on('keypress', 'focusout', $('input:text[name^="Customers[0].EmailAddresses"]'), function (e) {
    emailRadioBtns(e);
});
```

But this is not working. Does anyone know how to call the same function with multiple events using the .on()?

Comment: The selector for `on` should be just that; a selector, not a jQuery object like you're providing (pass `'input:text[name^="Customers[0].EmailAddresses"]'` instead of `$('input:text[name^="Customers[0].EmailAddresses"]')`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use instead

```
$('.EmailAddresses').on('keypress focusout', ...
```

all event names must be enclosed in the same string and separated by a white space

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.EmailAddresses').on('keypress focusout', 'input:text[name^="Customers[0].EmailAddresses"]', function (e) {
    emailRadioBtns(e);
});
```

or for different functions:

```
$('.EmailAddresses').on({
   keypress: function(e) {
       emailRadioBtns(e);
   },
   focusout: function(e) {
       //do something else
   }
}, 'input:text[name^="Customers[0].EmailAddresses"]' );
```

Comment: Yeah I know I need to go back and do more accepting. I will I just get busy and distracted at work! Then I forget